# Return thrust binary function

Tags: c++, templates, thrust

I'm trying to define a function that will return the desired type operator based on the content of a string. I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

impl.cpp

```
template <typename T> thrust::binary_function<T,T,bool>
 get_filter_operator(const std::string &op)
    if (op == "!=")
        return thrust::not_equal_to<T>();
    else if (op == ">")
        return thrust::greater<T>();
    else if (op == "<")
        return thrust::less<T>();
    else if (op == ">=")
        return thrust::greater_equal<T>();
    else if (op == "<=")
        return thrust::less_equal<T>();
    else
    {
        return thrust::equal_to<T>();
    }

template thrust::binary_function<float,float,bool> get_filter_operator<float>(const std::string &);
```

impl.h

```
template <typename T> thrust::binary_function<T, T, bool> get_filter_operator(const std::string &op);
```

How can I return a pointer to an arbitrary function like `thrust::not_equal_to<int>()`, or `thrust::equal_to<int>()`? I can't find the correct type to return.

**EDIT**

As requested, Compiler error:

In instantiation of ‘thrust::binary_function<T, T, bool> get_filter_operator(const string&) [with T = float; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:

error: could not convert ‘thrust::equal_to<float>()’ from ‘thrust::equal_to<float>’ to ‘thrust::binary_function<float, float, bool>’
         return thrust::equal_to()

**Update**

Ok sorry to not have mentioned this before: The problem with this is I can't use std::function because it would only work on host code. I wanted to use thrust binary functions so that I could use them both in the GPU and the CPU.

Comment: I can show you an approximation to this using functors, but it's not really an answer to your question.

Comment: I think the most straightforward way to get what you want  is to write a functor that does a `switch` over the desired filter operator. I don't think `thrust:not_equal_to` and friends help much here.

Comment: I ended up doing that, actually. I wanted to know if there was a more elegant way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I return a pointer to an arbitrary function like thrust::not_equal_to(), or thrust::equal_to()? 
>   I cant find the correct type to return

Each of the things that you are trying to return is a function of two arguments,
each of some type `T`, that returns `bool`. The correct return type is

```
std::function<bool(T, T)>
```

As in:

```
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
std::function<bool(T, T)>
get_filter_operator(const std::string &op)
{
    if (op == "!=")
        return thrust::not_equal_to<T>();
    else if (op == ">")
        return thrust::greater<T>();
    else if (op == "<")
        return thrust::less<T>();
    else if (op == ">=")
        return thrust::greater_equal<T>();
    else if (op == "<=")
        return thrust::less_equal<T>();
    else
    {
        return thrust::equal_to<T>();
    }
}

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto relop = get_filter_operator<int>("!=");
    cout << boolalpha << relop(1,0) << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << relop(1,1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, you may wish to re-iterate your comment to @MohamadElghawi:

> Yeah, I knew that worked, but the problem is that I'm trying to return a 
>   thrust::binary_function, not from std

That may be what you are trying to do, but it is the wrong thing to be
trying to do and an impossible thing to do. Look at the definition of
`template<typename A1, typename A2, typename R> struct thrust::binary_function`
in `<thrust/functional>` and at the associated documentation. Note:

> binary_function is an empty base class: it contains no member functions
>   or member variables, but only type information

In particular, `thrust::binary_function<A1,A2,R>` has no `operator()`.
It is not callable. It cannot store any other callable object (or
anything at all). See also the definitions of `equal_to`, `not_equal_to`,
etc. in the same file. `binary_function` is not a even base of any of them.
There is no conversion from any of them to `binary_function`.

Note too:

> binary_function is currently redundant with the C++ STL type
>   std::binary_function. We reserve it here for potential additional
>   functionality at a later date.

(`std::binary_function` is itself deprecated as of C++11 and will be removed in C++17).

`thrust::binary_function<T,T,bool>` is not what you are looking for. `std::function<bool(T, T)>`
is.

```
std::function<bool(int, int)> f = thrust::greater<int>();
```

makes `f` encapsulate a callable object that is a `thrust::greater<int>`

**Later**

> The problem with this is that it can only be used in host code doesnt it? 
>   The beauty of thrust binary functions is that they can be used both in the GPU and the CPU.

I think you may be under the impression that, e.g.

```
std::function<bool(int, int)> f = thrust::greater<int>();  /*A*/
```

takes a `thrust::greater<int>` and in some manner *downgrades* it into a
`std::function<bool(int, int)>` that has similar but more restricted
("std") execution capabilities.

Nothing like that is the case. An `std::function<bool(int, int)> foo` is simply a receptacle for 
anything `bar` that is callable with two arguments that are implicitly 
convertible to `int` and returns something implicitly convertible to `bool`, 
such that if:

```
std::function<bool(int, int)> foo = bar;
```

then when you call `foo(i,j)` you are returned the result, as `bool`, of 
*executing* `bar(i,j)`. Not the result of executing anything that is in any way different
from `bar(i,j)`.

Thus in `/*A*/` above, the callable thing contained by, and called by, `f` *is a*
thrust binary function; it *is a* `thrust::greater<int>()`. The method that
is invoked by the `f`'s `operator()` *is* `thrust::greater<int>::operator()`.

Here is a program:

```
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto thrust_greater_than_int = thrust::greater<int>();
    std::function<bool(int, int)> f = thrust_greater_than_int;
    cout << "f " 
        << (f.target<thrust::greater<int>>() ? "calls" : "does not call") 
        << " a thrust::greater<int>" << endl;
    cout << "f " 
        << (f.target<thrust::equal_to<int>>() ? "calls" : "does not call") 
        << " a thrust::equal_to<int>" << endl;
    cout << "f " 
        << (f.target<std::greater<int>>() ? "calls" : "does not call") 
        << " an std::greater<int>" << endl;
    cout << "f " 
        << (f.target<std::function<bool(int,int)>>() ? "calls" : "does not call") 
        << " an std::function<bool(int,int)>" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

that stores a `thrust::greater<int>` in a `std::function<bool(int, int)> f`
and then informs you that:

```
f calls a thrust::greater<int>
f does not call a thrust::equal_to<int>
f does not call an std::greater<int>
f does not call an std::function<bool(int,int)>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it can only be used in host code doesnt it? The beauty of thrust binary functions is that they can be used both in the GPU and the CPU. Otherwise I would have just used std functions and not used thrust at all

Comment: @gumlyn Update nay help.

Comment: ok, sorry to not have mentioned that before, i didnt think of it

Answer (score 1):

Even though there was no exact answer, I'm going to put here what I have ended up using, in case someone needs something similar.

In a .cuh file

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

namespace BinaryFunction
{
    enum class ComparisonOperator
    {
      equal_to,
      not_equal_to,
      greater,
      less,
      greater_equal,
      less_equal
    };

    enum class BitwiseOperator
    {
      bit_and,
      bit_or
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct CompareFunction
    {
      __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs, ComparisonOperator &op) const
      {
            switch (op)
            {
                case ComparisonOperator::equal_to:
                    return lhs==rhs;
                case ComparisonOperator::not_equal_to:
                    return lhs!=rhs;
                case ComparisonOperator::greater:
                    return lhs>rhs;
                case ComparisonOperator::less:
                    return lhs<rhs;
                case ComparisonOperator::greater_equal:
                    return lhs>=rhs;
                case ComparisonOperator::less_equal:
                    return lhs<=rhs;

            }
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct BitwiseFunction
    {
      __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs, BitwiseOperator &op) const
      {
        if (op==BitwiseOperator::bit_and)
          return lhs & rhs;
        else if (op==BitwiseOperator::bit_or)
          return lhs | rhs;
      }
    };
}
```

Then use it like this:
In the cpp file:

```
BinaryFunction::ComparisonOperator comp_op = BinaryFunction::ComparisonOperator::equal_to;

BinaryFunction::CompareFunction<int> comp_func;
```

And then, in the kernel or in a normal function:

```
int value_a;
int value_b;
comp_func(value_a, value_b, comp_op)
```

Comment: Doesn't this impact performance by doing the switch for every value, inside if the kernel, instead of before the kernel is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
std::function<bool(T, T)> GetOperator(const std::string& op)
{
    if (op == "!=")
        return std::not_equal_to<T>();
    else if (op == ">")
        return std::greater<T>();
    else if (op == "<")
        return std::less<T>();
    else if (op == ">=")
        return std::greater_equal<T>();
    else if (op == "<=")
        return std::less_equal<T>();
    else
    {
        return std::equal_to<T>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto op = GetOperator<int>(">");
    std::cout << op(1, 2) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew that worked, but the problem is that im trying to return a thrust::binary_function, not from std

Comment: @gumlym What error(s) do you get. I have never used thrust before but a quick look at the docs show that your code should work (apart from the missing braces).